# Specify my own appender (or behavior) with Log4j logging utility

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j

I have the following Log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, ONE, TWO

log4j.appender.ONE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ONE.File=logs/one.log
log4j.appender.ONE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.ONE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ONE.layout.ConversionPattern= %-5p [%t]  %c - %m%n


log4j.appender.TWO=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TWO.File=logs/TWO.log
log4j.appender.TWO.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.TWO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TWO.layout.ConversionPattern= %-5p [%t]  %c - %m%n
```

The only difference is the log file location. Is there a programmatic method in which I am able to choose which appender to use.

I.E

```
if(Config.getInstance().equals("One"))
     //Use appender ONE
else
     //use appender TWO
```

My current thought/solution is to have two properties file and use the set property method. However, I was curious to know if there was an alternative solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    //Using system args instead of Config
    final Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    Appender ap = null;
    if (args[0].equals("1")) {
        ap = rootLogger.getAppender("TWO");
    } else if ( args[0].equals("2") ) {
        ap = rootLogger.getAppender("ONE");
    }
    if (ap != null) { 
        rootLogger.removeAppender(ap);
    }
```